# tengo error de sintaxis Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, nodejs

al querer usar la funcion me sale el siguiente error: **SyntaxError: Fin inesperado de la entrada**

Esta es la funcion que quiero utilizar

```
Persona.findAll().then(function (personas) {

personas.forEach(function(elemento) {

 console.log(elemento.dataValues);

});
```

Comment: Que devuelve la funcion `findAll()` ?

Comment: Actualmente en el código que muestras te falta un cierre: `});`. Verifica eso.